# Ubuntu works great; can't boot into previously-working Win 10 partition after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows, mac

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro (14, 1) [This is not a Mac with the evil T2 chip.]

Prior to installing Ubuntu,I could boot into OSX and Windows.
After installing Ubuntu 2020.10, I have the following experience:

- if I press nothing while booting, I get the GRUB menu. Choosing Ubuntu [first + default, works fine]: my Ubuntu desktop works great
- If I choose Windows, my screen goes blank and does nothing.
- If I hold down option/alt during power on, I get a graphical display of 2 drives (I believe this is my UEFI startup menu?). Choosing Apple boots me into OSX Fine.
- If I hold down option/alt and choose Windows, I get some quick-flashing text and boot into Ubuntu.

Before installing Ubuntu, I used gparted from the USB to shrink my NTFS partition, and installed Ubuntu on that new partition. My NTFS partition seems fine and mounts successfully.

I tried boot-repair with the default options; this didn't change anything, but I do have this report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dP6RmzTRvk/

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I would not have chosen gparted from the USB to shrink my NTFS partition. Windows provides a Disk Management tool for this purpose. Also, you can use the `diskpart` command while booted to the Windows Recovery Environment (WRE). You can enter the WRE by holding down the shift key when restarting Windows.

When both Windows and Ubuntu use the same EFI partition, there will exist a conflict between the duplicate use of some filenames and folder locations. For example, `/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`.

One solution would be to create a second EFI partition when installing Ubuntu. After the installation is complete, move the Ubuntu Grub boot files to this new EFI partition and restore the overwritten Windows boot files in the original EFI partition. And example of how to do this is given in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408450/move-grub-from-sd-card-to-win-partition/408464#408464). In your case, the two EFI partitions will reside on the same drive.

Comment: Thanks, @david-anderson. I did mean OPTION, not ESC. I'll dig into the linked answer. I appreciate your help!